# Настройка date в MySQL

Tags: mysql

MySQL настроена так, что принимает значения даты только в формате `хххх-хх-хх`, подскажите пожалуйста, как настроить её, чтобы MySQL сама преобразовывала дату в нужный формат (к примеру, вставляем в неё пустое значение, а она интерпретирует его как `0000-00-00` и тд).
зы: версия 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL хранит дату только в удобном для него формате - YYYY-MM-DD. Все манипуляции с датой/временем при использовании СУБД MySQL производятся на стороне клиента (PHP, C++, Delphi, ...), путём строковых преобразований.

[Источник](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html)

> DATE
>
> A date. The supported range is
> '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'. MySQL
> displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD'
> format, but permits assignment of
> values to DATE columns using either
> strings or numbers.
>
> DATETIME
>
> A date and time combination. The
> supported range is '1000-01-01
> 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
> MySQL displays DATETIME values in
> 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format, but
> permits assignment of values to
> DATETIME columns using either strings
> or numbers.

Comment: Может, я чего не понял, гляньте пожалуйста на ссылку:
[Проблемы с использованием столбцов типа DATE](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Using_DATE.html).
В документации написано, что mysql преобразует всё как надо, да и у меня стоит denwer, в нём mysql работает как написано по ссылке.

Comment: Там говорится о том, что используется мягкая проверка. В место дефисов можно использовать другие знаки препинания. А вот переставлять местами год, месяц и день - нельзя. А если ты вставляешь NULL в поле с датой, и это поле допускает пустые значения, то и выводиться при выборке тоже должен NULL.

[Например][1].

  [1]: http://shot.photo.qip.ru/004ki2-202M2Ft/

Comment: Наверное, я плохо сформулировал вопрос)) Вот мне как раз и нужна "мягкая проверка".

Comment: Тогда, вперед. :)

Только SELECT-ы все равно будут возвращать YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: куда вперед))в том то и проблема что этой "мягкой проверки" нет, вот пытаюсь узнать как её включить)

Comment: Допустимые форматы для мягкой проверки: `19970505`, `'19970505'`, `'97-05-05'`, `'1997.05.05'`, `'1997 05 05'`, `'1997-05-05'` и т.д.

`''` (пустая строка) - недопустимый формат. Потому что дата это не строка. Такое преобразование нужно делать на уровне приложения, а после преобразования уже писать в запрос к БД.

Comment: ага..ну с пустой строкой ясно, хотя в denwer'е работает и с пустой(вставляется 0000-00-00)

но вот с другим разделителем не работает, только с "-"

Comment: Все же, не там копаешь.

Обрабатывать поступившие данные нужно приложением, а не базой. Смысл в том, чтобы отслеживать ошибки ввода данных и выдавать юзеру соответствующее сообщение, не доходя до записи в БД. Плюс, часто, ошибки могут иметь не только синтаксически характер. Это может быть какая-то специфическая логика приложения. Например, ввод даты ограниченной периодом.

Все нормальные фреймворки практикуют такой подход к обработке ввода. Есть форма ввода данных, и на каждый элемент, если нужно, вешается свой фильтр и свой валидатор. А в БД пишутся только проверенные и подготовленные данные